# Zend Paginator variable

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination, zend-paginator

I'm trying to use `Zend_Paginator` with `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` to get data rowset.

I've faced with problem in receive data from variable.

My error content

> "**Fatal error:** Cannot use object of type Zend_Paginator as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\applications\quickstart\application\views\scripts\index\text.phtml on line 8"

Text.php:

```
class Application_Model_Text extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'text';

    public function getTexts($page)
    {
        $query = $this->select();

        $paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($query));
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page)->setItemCountPerPage(2);

        return $paginator;
    }
}
```

IndexController.php:

```
public function textAction()
{
    $page = $this->getParam('page');
    $textModel = new Application_Model_Text();
    $data = $textModel->getTexts($page);
    $this->view->text = $data;
}
```

pagination.phtml:

```
<div id="pagination">
    <?php $pageVariable = ($this->page)?$this->page: 'page' ?>
    <a href="<?= $this->url(array($pageVariable => $this->previous)) ?>">Back</a>
    <p>Strona <?= $this->current ?></p>
    <a href="<?= $this->url(array($pageVariable => $this->next)) ?>">Next</a>
</div>
```

text.phtml:

```
<?php $text = $this->text; ?>
<div id="pagination-box">
    <?= $this->paginationControl($text, 'Sliding', array('pagination.phtml', 'default')) ?>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="text">
        <p><?= $text['text'] ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone has idea what I'm doing wrong?
I'm new to Zend but I really enjoy that framework.
In advance thank's for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
<div id="text">
    <p><?= $text['text'] ?></p>
</div>
```

To ('text' is a set of items so you need to iterate) :

```
<?php foreach($text as $row):?>
  <div id="text">
  <?= $row->text ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Zend paginator returns array of rowsets, so in your `index.phtml` file `$text` is not an array, it is an object. Try to work with properties, like:

```
<?= $text->text; ?>
```

Comment: I've try it already, and i got: <br/> 

Notice: Undefined property: Zend_Paginator::$text in C:\xampp\htdocs\applications\quickstart\application\views\scripts\index\text.phtml on line 7